# Move fstab onto another partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

I am currently making a from USB bootable Ubuntu, which I want to use from USB. The thing is, that I want to save stuff like keyboard settings. I achieved moving ~ to the new partition, but when I restart the machine the fstab file gets reset (so the ~ directory is set back to the first partition). Is there any way for me to move fstab to the second partition? Or just to save the fstab settings on live?

Comment: To save settings on a USB you need to have made a persistent live USB. Search on how to make that.

Comment: I made a persistent partition and moved the ~ to there (because the user settings such as keyboard layout are saved in ~). That worked until I rebooted the system. That caused for the fstab to be reset and the ~ is moved back again

Comment: Not a partition the whole USB should be made as a persistent OS.

Comment: You have to match the UUIDs in fstab and grub.cfg to those in your new system (in the USB drive). And they should be different from those in the internal drive. Otherwise there will be confusion.